# Update Map based on another nested Map iteration

Tags: elixir

Immutability in Elixir is really blowing my mind and makes the languages so confusing to use. I need to iterate a nested map and simple update some counts based on the iteration, but `Enum.reduce` just makes it difficult for me. Say I have:

```
defmodule Predictor do

  def past_matches() do
    [
      team1: %{team2: %{f: 0, a: 1},  team3: %{f: 1, a: 3}},
      team2: %{team1: %{f: 3, a: 0},  team3: %{f: 2, a: 0}},                    
      team3: %{team1: %{f: 1, a: 0},  team2: %{f: 0, a: 1}},
    ]
  end


  def init_indexes(matches) do
    local = Enum.reduce matches, %{}, fn({team, _scores}, acc) ->
      Map.put acc, team, %{f: 0, a: 0, n_games: 0}
    end

    Enum.each matches, fn({team, scores}) ->
      Enum.each scores, fn({vteam, %{f: ff, a: aa}}) ->
        %{f: fi, a: ai, n_games: ni} = local[team]
        put_in(local[team], %{f: fi+ff, a: ai+aa, n_games: ni+1})
      end
    end

    local
  end

  def run() do
    local = past_matches() |> init_indexes()
  end
end
```

I need `local` to just sum `f`,`a` and `n_games`.

```
local = %{
    team1: %{f: 1, a: 4, n_games: 2}
    ...
}
```

At the end of `run()` obviously the Map `local` has all 0's and no updated value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things I can see off the bat that are tripping you up:

- `Enum.each/2` will apply a function to every item in a list, but it doesn't accumulate the results or modify the original list in any way. I can't remember the last time I used `Enum.each` -- it has its place, but it's pretty rare.
- What that means is that the places where you're calling `local[team]` aren't actually updating any values because that output is not being passed through to anything else. It's essentially just sending those changes into the ether.
- The solution: pipes! I promise you that the `|>` pipe operator will change your life. It's a little mind-boggly at first if you come from an OO background, but stick with it and I promise you will never want to go back. The shift in thinking that helped me wrap my head around it was to use as few anonymous functions as possible at first. It helped me adjust to the concept of immutability because it forced me to think about what values each function actually needs, and how to pass those values to each function.

Here's my stab at rewriting your module using a more pipeline-centric approach -- hope it helps. It produces the expected results when you run it in IEx. I'm happy to clarify anything if you have questions.

```
defmodule Predictor do

  @past_matches [
    team1: %{
      team2: %{f: 0, a: 1},
      team3: %{f: 1, a: 3}
    },
    team2: %{
      team1: %{f: 3, a: 0},
      team3: %{f: 2, a: 0}
    },
    team3: %{
      team1: %{f: 1, a: 0},
      team2: %{f: 0, a: 1}
    }
  ]

  # see note 1    
  @baseline %{f: 0, a: 0, n_games: 0}

  def run(past_matches \\ @past_matches) do
    past_matches
    |> Enum.map(&build_histories/1)
    |> Enum.into(%{}) 
    # see note 2
  end

  def build_histories({team, scores}) do
    history = Enum.reduce(scores, @baseline, &build_history/2)
    {team, history}
  end

  def build_history({_vteam, vresults}, acc) do
    # see note 3
    %{acc | f: acc.f + vresults.f,
            a: acc.a + vresults.a,
            n_games: acc.n_games + 1}
  end
end

(1) since the baseline is the same for every team, you can 
    set it as a module attribute -- basically like setting a global 
    (immutable) variable that you can use as a starting point for a new 
    value. Another option would be to create a %BaseLine{} struct that 
    has default values.

(2) you could also use `Enum.reduce/2` here instead, but this does 
    effectively the same thing -- the output of the `Enum.map/1` 
    call is a list of {atom, _val} which is interpreted as a Keyword 
    list; calling `Enum.into(%{}) turns a Keyword list into a map 
    (and vice versa with `Enum.into([])`).

(3) NB:  %{map | updated_key: updated_val} only works on maps or 
    structs where the key to be updated already exists -- it'll throw 
    an error if the key isn't found on the original map.
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful !